# AWS EKS service ingress and ALB --no ADDRESS

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I seem to be having an issue with the way my ports are setup on this manifest, which is a simple go app. The app is configured to listen on port 3000.
This container runs fine on my local machine (localhost:3000), but I get no ADDRESS when I look at the Ingress (k get ingress ...).
I am getting an error logged in the AWS aws-load-balancer-controller log when I try to run this image on EKS:

```
controller-runtime.manager.controller.ingress","msg":"Reconciler error","name":"fiber-demo","namespace":"demo","error":"ingress: demo/fiber-demo: unable to find port 3000 on service demo/fiber-demo"
```

This is my k8s manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fiber-demo
  namespace: demo
  labels:
    app: fiber-demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fiber-demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fiber-demo
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                  - key: kubernetes.io/arch
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - amd64
                      - arm64
      containers:
        - name: fiber-demo
          image: 240195868935.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/fiber-demo:0.0.2
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fiber-demo
  namespace: demo
  labels:
    app: fiber-demo
spec:
  selector:
    app: fiber-demo
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 3000

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fiber-demo
  namespace: demo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing

  labels:
    app: fiber-demo
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: fiber-demo
              servicePort: 3000
```

Am I simply not able to specify a targetPort other than port 80 in the Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I simply not able to specify a targetPort other than port 80 in the Service?

`backend.servicePort` refers to port exposed by **service**, not container.

```
...
backend:
  serviceName: fiber-demo  # <-- ingress for this service, not container
  servicePort: 80          # <-- port which the service exposed, not the port which the container exposed.
```

Comment: Thanks! I did change servicePort to 80 , but was still getting "Backend service not available" when testing with the Ingress address.  Then I added  "type: LoadBalancer" to the Service , and I was able to get my Hello World page up.